# Exercise on relatively compact set of analytic functions on the unit disk

Tags: complex-analysis, compactness, analytic-functions

**CONTEXT**

I need some help in solving an exercise from Conway's book "Functions of One Complex Variable I".

> Let $D = \{z: |z| <1\}$ and show that $\mathcal F$ is normal iff there is a sequence $\{M_n\}$ of positive constants such that $\limsup \sqrt[n]{M_n} \leq 1$ and if $f(z) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n z^n$, then $|a_n|\leq M_n$ for all $n$.

In this context normal means *relatively compact*.

**WHAT I HAVE DONE**

I managed to prove one of the two implications. Assume the existence of the sequence $\{M_n\}$. Then for each compact set $K\subset D$ there exists $r<1$ such that $K\subset \overline B(0,r) \subset D$, where $\overline B(0,r) = \{z:|z| \leq r\}$. Take $N$ large enough so that $M_n< \frac1{r}$. Then we have, for all $f\in \mathcal F$ and for all $z\in K$,
\begin{eqnarray}|f(z)| &\leq& \sum_{n=0}^\infty |a_n| |z^n|=\sum_{n=0}^N M_n r^n + \sum_{n=N+1}^\infty \frac1{r}r^n\leq\\
&\leq&\max_{0\leq n\leq N} (M_n)\frac{1-r^{N+1}}{1-r}+\frac1{1-r}.\end{eqnarray}
Then we can use Montel's Theorem to deduce relative compactness of $\mathcal F$.

As for the other implication, I guess one could use again Montel's Theorem to state the fact that, for any $r < 1$, for all $f\in F$ and for all $z\in \overline B(0,r)$ there is a constant $J_r$ such that $$|f(z)| \leq J_r.$$ Then
$$|a_n| = \frac1{2\pi} \left|\int_{\gamma_r} \frac{f(z)}{z^{n+1}} dz\right|\leq \frac{J_r}{r^n},$$
but, since $J_r$ depends on $r$, I don't know how to use this bound to reach the required conclusion.

**QUESTIONS**

Is the first part of the exercise correct? Can you give me a hint on how to proceed to prove the inverse implication?

Comment: the first part looks good as for the second part use contradiction and assume that exists $\delta >1$ st for infinitely many $n_k$ there is $f_{k}=\sum a_{km}z^m \in F$ with the $n_k$th coefficient $f, |a_{kn_k}| \ge \delta^{n_k}$; extract a convergent subsequence (call it also) $f_k \to f$ and show that if $f=\sum a_nz^n$ then say $a_{n_k}(2/(1+\delta))^{n_k}$ doesn;t converge to zero, hence the power series of $f$ doesn't converge at $2/(1+\delta) <1$

Comment: @Conrad Thanks for the hint. I am working on the details of the proof along the path you indicated!

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to [Conrad](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/298272/conrad)'s hint in comments, I should have been able to complete the exercise. Here is my attempt to the rest of the proof. Please have a look and feel free to correct/comment on it.

Suppose the assertion on the $a_n$'s is not true. Then for some $\delta>1$, there exist and sequence of positive integers $n_1,n_2,\dots$ and corresponding functions $f_{n_1},f_{n_2},\dots\in \mathcal F$, with
$$f_k(z) = \sum_{h=1}^\infty a_{k,h} z^h,$$ such that $|a_{k,n_k}|>\delta^{n_k}$.

Normality implies that $\{f_k\}$ has a subsequence $\{f_{k_1},f_{k_2},\dots\}$ that converge to some $f \in H(D)$, with
$$f(z) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n z^n.$$

In particular we have, for each $m$,
$$|a_{k_m,n_{k_m}}| \to |a_{n_{k_m}}|.$$

Since $|a_{k_m,n_{k_m}}|\geq \delta^{n_{k_m}}$, it follows that
$$|a_{n_{k_m}}|\geq \delta^{n_{k_m}}.$$

Finally noting that
$$\left|a_{n_{k_m}} \cdot \left(\frac{2}{1+\delta}\right)^{n_{k_m}}\right|\geq \left(\frac{2\delta}{1+\delta}\right)^{n_{k_m}}\not \to 0,$$
we conclude that the function $f(z)$ does not converge in $z= \frac{2}{1+\delta} <1$, a contradiction.

Comment: the above is not quite correct since you only know that $a_{k,n_k}$ is large but not necessarily $a_{m, n_k}$ for $m >k$ and when you go to the limit, $k$ is fixed and the limit is in $m$; the way to do it is consider the convergence on the closed disc of radius $c=2/(\delta+1)$ where it is uniform, this means $\max |f_k-f| \le 1$ say uniformly in $k \ge k_0$ on the closed disc, so using Cauchy you get $|(a_{k,n_k}-a_{n_k})c^{n_k}| \le 1$ so $|a_{n_k}c^{n_k}| \ge |a_{k,n_k}c^{n_k}|-1\ge (c\delta)^{n_k}-1$ and by our choice we have that $c\delta >1$ so the contradiction follows

Comment: @Conrad, thanks again, you're right. I struggled at that point and in fact I made a mistake. I'll amend it as soon as possible.

Comment: No problem and happy to be of help; one needs to use the full power of analyticity here, so Cauchy theorem appears (or of course one can use Parseval to uniformly bound the single terms of the power series)